# How to prevent custom header from blinking on section update?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Does anyone know how to get a custom section header/footer view from blinking on reload of a section?

```
Section(header:"",footer:"") {section in
    section.tag = "main"
    var header = HeaderFooterView<GenericSection>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
    header.onSetupView = { v,s in
        v.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 30, height: 20 )
        v.label.text = self.row.title
        v.label.numberOfLines = 0
        v.label.textAlignment = .Justified
        v.label.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
        v.label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.47, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)
        v.label.frame = v.label.bounds
        v.label.sizeToFit()
        v.bounds = CGRect(x: -8, y: -8, width: v.label.bounds.width - 15, height: v.label.bounds.height + 25)
    }
    section.header = header
    section.footer = nil
}
```

If I use `Section(header:"test",footer:"test2")` the header view never blinks on any form modifications which is what I want. However, I am using a custom margins and adding icons to the headers which is why I need custom views to serve as the header/footer. Is there a property that I am not setting on the .onSetupView that would resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is related to your `header` view reload over and over again, and adjust his frame over and over again, so you can fix this simply adding a `bool` variable like this

With issue
[image]

Without issue [image]

```
class GenericSection: UIView {
    let label = UILabel()
    var positioned = false
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.bounds.size.width - 30, height: 40)
        self.addSubview(label)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and then

```
form +++ Section(header:"",footer:"") {section in
            section.tag = "main"
            var header = HeaderFooterView<GenericSection>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
            header.onSetupView = { v,s in
                if(!v.positioned)
                {
                v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
                v.layer.borderWidth = 1
                v.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 30, height: 20 )
                v.label.text = "Testing Custom Header without issue"
                v.label.numberOfLines = 0
                v.label.textAlignment = .Justified
                v.label.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
                v.label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.47, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)
                v.label.frame = v.label.bounds
                v.label.sizeToFit()
                v.bounds = CGRect(x: -8, y: -8, width: v.label.bounds.width - 15, height: v.label.bounds.height + 25)
                v.setNeedsLayout()
                v.setNeedsDisplay()
                v.positioned = true
                }
            }
            section.header = header
            section.footer = nil
        }
```

I hope this helps you, regards

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your detailed response to my question! I forgot to update the question with my version of a workaround; I overrode the tableView viewForHeaderInSection, viewForFooterInSection, and heightForHeaderInSection. Then I can pass along my string and set-up the label in those methods according to my styling parameters (I use 0 inset for separators so that I have full width lines between cells). With your method, wouldn't the problem be that if it's a long section, that as soon as I scroll back up, it would not re-draw the section because the v.positioned value would be 'true'?

Comment: Yes, it works without having to create any custom views/classes. I just string initialize the section such as "section(header: "Some header", footer: "") and then the overridden methods take care of the rendering. No blinking, no other drawing issues.

Comment: Nice then, I use the description that you provide for your issue, but if you resolve that, well done then!. regards